# session variable are not working

Tags: php, session, session-variables

am trying to pass the values from one page to another page using $_SESSION
it is not working

```
<?php

    $_SESSION['id']="12";
    $_SESSION['fname']="harsha";
    $_SESSION['date1']="2013-06-27";
    $_SESSION['time']="06:35:00";
    header('location:ex1.php');
?>
```

am trying to pass values from ex1.php to ex2.php

in ex2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$fname=$_SESSION['fname'];
$date=$_SESSION['date1'];
$time=$_SESSION['time']; 
?>
```

if am trying to print the values nothing is displaying.

how to solve it...help me..

Comment: You need a `session_start` in any file where you're setting or reading from a session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the session in `ex1.php`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id']="12";
    $_SESSION['fname']="harsha";
    $_SESSION['date1']="2013-06-27";
    $_SESSION['time']="06:35:00";
    header('location:ex1.php');
?>
```